# simulate referer iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

my question is this

I have 2 sites, SiteA, SiteB, and what I want is to pretend that the traffic of a website through an open iframe in SiteA, simulate SiteB come from, for example we have:

*SitioA.com/index.php

*SitioB.com/redirect.php (Placed a javascript that redirects to the site I want it to open in the iframe, so the javascript code clears the referrer)

In SitioA.com/index.php, I put an iframe to call SitioB.com/redirect.php, which, in turn redirects with javascript to the web that I want to simulate the referer, here I leave the code to understand better:

In SitioA.com/Index.php I put:

```
<iframe class="premium_frame" src="http://SitioB.com/redirect.php" width="1000" height="1000" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In sitioB.com/redirect.php, I put:

```
window.location.href = "http://jaqhegrjghegr.com";
```

Doing this is no way to jaqhegrjghegr.com for example, discover that the check actually comes from SiteA and not SiteB? that's my question

Comment: I'm not sure what are you actually asking, but [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) is probably related?

Comment: @Teemu thanks for replying, all we want to know is, if I create an iframe in SiteA.com directed to a PHP with javascript in sitioB.com, that redirects any site, that site could detect that is being opened in an iframe in SiteA com, or only detects the visitor comes from sitioB.com (php with javascript that redirects X site), for example:

SiteA.com iframe (opens siteB.com/redirect.php) -> siteB.com/redirect.php has a javascript that redirects Example.com, Example.com detected as SiteA origin? or a siteB? that's my question

Comment: @Teemu the only thing I want is for the visitor creates Example.com comes SiteB.com/redirect.php, not SiteA.com though the iframe is in SiteA.com